# make selection in a whole document

Tags: vba, ms-word

in a file MS WORD I wish to select a "/" and make bold all characters till the following ^p. The following code works well only for the first occurrence. In the file I have many occurrences and I am not able to apply this in the whole file. I tried several times with "for...next" and others, unfortuntely without success.

Many thanks for your help! Gianluca

```
Sub bold_title()

Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
 .Text = "/"
  .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.Extend
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^p"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = False

End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.Font.Bold = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to "collapse" the `Selection`- think of it like pressing the right-arrow key - so that the next search starts *after* the "found" text:

```
Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
```

Usually, a `Do While...Loop` construct is used in order to repeat the `Find` until the end of the document. You'll find lots and lots of examples if you search here and elsewhere on the Internet.

For this to work successfully, make sure you set `Wrap` to `wdFindStop` (and not `wdFindContinue` as is currently in the code shown).